# How to multiply and then add the values of two table columns using Knex.js?

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I need to multiply the values from `column_A` and `column_B` of a table `table_A` and then add them using `knex.js`. Following is the code which I am using to achieve it, which is resulting in an error:

```
knex().from('table_A').raw('sum(column_A * column_B) as column_c')
```

Any pointers to what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works better:

```
knex('table_A').select(
  knex.raw('sum(?? * ??) as ??', ['column_A', 'column_B', 'column_C'])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
knex('table_a')
  .columns([
    knex.raw('sum(column_a * column_b) as column_c')
  ])
  .first()
  .then((rows) => {
    console.log(rows); //log { column_c: 500 }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me . You can use knexraw query to get object

```
async getTotal(user_id){
 return await
                    this.knex.raw('SELECT sum(cart.qty * product_item.price) as sub_total\n' +
                        'FROM cart \n' +
                        'JOIN product_item ON cart.product_item_id = product_item.id\n' +
                        'WHERE cart.user_id=39');
}
```